# Show for set-function P((a,b]) = F(b) - F(a)...

Tags: probability-theory

How can I show the following:

given: $\Omega$ = $\mathbb{R}$; X($\omega$) = $\omega$.  Set-function $\mathbb{P}$((a; b]) = F (b) − F (a)

wanted: Show $\mathbb{P}$($\mathbb{R}$)=1 and $\mathbb{P}$(X $\lt$ x) = F (x) for any x $\in \mathbb{R}$

@ $\mathbb{P}$($\mathbb{R}$)=1:

Ω = $\mathbb{R}$ and X($\omega$) = $\omega$ $\iff$ mapping to any point on the real line $\iff$ $\mathbb{R^1}$ = $\cup$ (-n,n]?

So $\mathbb{P}$($\mathbb{R^1}$) = $\lim_{n\to \infty}$F(n) - $\lim_{n\to +\infty}$F(-n) = 1-0 = 1 ?

@ $\mathbb{P}$(X $\lt$ x) = F (x)

$\mathbb{P}$(X $\lt$ x) = $\mathbb{P}$({$\omega \in \Omega$: X($\omega$)<x}) = F(x)?

This is what I came up with so far. Is this correct? What do I need to add, esp. to the second part?

Thanks!

Comment: You did not say what $F$ is. $P(X<x)=F(X)$ is not even true if $F$ is a CDF in the usual sense.

Comment: P(X<x)=F(X) is part of the instruction and unfortenately not further defined. I think, P(X<x)=F(X) means left-continuous instead of right-continuous in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that $F$ is left-continuous, increasing with $F(\infty)=1$ and $F(-\infty)=0$.

Your proof is correct for the first part.

$\mathbb P(-n,x]=F(x)-F(-n)$ and letting $n \to \infty$ gives $\mathbb P (-\infty, x]=F(x)$ so  $\mathbb P (X<x)=\mathbb P (-\infty,x)=\lim \mathbb P (-\infty,x-\frac 1 n]=\lim F(x-\frac 1 n)=F(x)$ by left-continuity.

Comment: thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: 1 question to the last line: is this the lim for n->∞?

Comment: Yes, that is right.